# Log4j logging two times in logging file

Tags: java, log4j

Here is my log4j.xml

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
      <appender name="mylog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
       <param name="File" value="myLogfile.log" />
       <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
       <param name="append" value="true"/>
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>          
       </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
        <logger name="com.mypackage1">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="mylog" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root> 

</log4j:configuration>
```

in myLogfile.log file i am getting the logging from "com.mypackage1" two times.

Please help put with the issue

Comment: Probably because you keep copy-pasting stuff multiple times. Probably because you keep copy-pasting stuff multiple times. Probably because you keep copy-pasting stuff multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for notifying my mistake. This was my first post. anyways i have edited it.

Comment: Try to remove <appender-ref ref="mylog" />

Comment: That logging configuration file will not cause duplicates in the `myLogfile.log` file. It *will* cause duplicates in the console output, but that's different. If you see duplicates in the file, then you probably call the log statements twice, or perhaps you load the configuration file twice without resetting.

Answer (score -1):

If you are redirecting your console output to the same log file from shell, like you mentioned in the comment, then yes, your log file will have duplicate entries. One solution would be to use below log4j config in your program and redirect the console output to a different file - e.g. `console.out`, that will have your logs and std out separate. If you must have std out in the same file, then redirect std out to the same file.

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
      <appender name="mylog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
       <param name="File" value="myLogfile.log" />
       <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
       <param name="append" value="true"/>
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>          
       </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mypackage1">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="mylog" />
    <!-- <appender-ref ref="console" />  -->    
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
    <!--  <appender-ref ref="console" />  -->
          <appender-ref ref="myLog" />
    </root> 

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: The `console` appender would not cause duplicate entries in the `myLogfile.log` file written to by the `mylog` appender.

Comment: Yep, my bad. I misread the question, I thought duplicate entries were on the console. For duplicates in file, this log4j wouldn't be doing it. However, I suspect it may be the way the program might have been executed - e.g. launched from shell and output redirected to the file, probably? That might cause duplicate in file, I guess. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: yes my program is launched from shell but is there any way to fix this

Comment: Use the config in my answer above and you can keep redirecting the output of the program to the same log file - though, I would advise to redirect std out to a different file than log file.